# Load external URL content using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following JQuery gets content of an external url:

```
var url = 'example.com/editor/stores/10';
$('#storeArticlePublish_Channel').load(url);
```

I do not want to use JQuery. How would I do this using normal javascript?

Comment: *"But I do not know how to write it in javascript"* That **is** writing it in JavaScript. What you're really asking is how to do it without jQuery, just using the APIs built into the browser (the DOM and `XMLHttpRequest`).

Comment: Yes, I do not want to use it with jQuery

Comment: Well, where are you stuck? What research have you done? What does your attempt to do it look like?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest object for this.To make a request:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The 'URL' is the url you want to execute/open.
The 3rd parameter is for async request, it can be either true or false.
And to get the result in *#storeArticlePublish_Channel* element, you can simply use this in the next line:

```
document.getElementById("storeArticlePublish_Channel").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: I hope it helped you. Also, if you want to support old versions of IE then you can have a look at: [This reference link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp)

Comment: Does not work as it triggers the cross origin error blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.